# How to call an API with certain time interval in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am working in an Angular 4 application,In this I need to call an API from my service file .

Here I call the method in service file every 15 minutes interval .But it shows an error as follows

[image]

but If I call the API without passing parameters it's working fine ,When I call a method from service which pass parameters to API it's not get triggered.

service method

```
update_User_Session() {
    this.publicIp.v4().then(ip => {
      this.END_USER_SESSION(ip)
    })

    this.publicIp.v4().then(ip => {
      this.INSERT_USER_SESSION(ip)
    })
  }

  INSERT_USER_SESSION(address: string) {
    this.http.get(`http://localhost:xyz/api/data/INSERT_USER_SESSION/?IP_Address=${address}&Time=${this.date_and_time}&state=${this.session_Begin_Status}`)
  }

  END_USER_SESSION(address: string) {
    this.http.get(`http://localhost:xyz/api/data/INSERT_END_USER_SESSION/?Ip_Address=${address}&Time=${this.date_and_time}&state=${this.session_End_Status}`)
  }
```

From my component

```
constructor(private CartdataService: CartdataService, private http: HttpClient) {

        this.call = Observable.interval(90000)
            .switchMap(() => this.CartdataService.update_User_Session())
            .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            });
    }
```

here this line `.switchMap(() => this.CartdataService.update_User_Session())` gets red lined and shows the above error as in the image

Can anyone tell me ,Where I did the mistakes.

Comment: your `update_User_Session ` should return an `Observable`,but you return `null`

Answer (score 0):

```
//use retryWhen from rxjs like below
//first  import retryWhen and delay operators in your service file.
//use before subscribe like below example as i given.

import 'rxjs/add/operator/retrywhen';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

ngOnInit() {
    let empCode: string = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params['code'];

    this._employeeService.getEmployeeByCode(empCode)
        // Retry with a delay of 1000 milliseconds (i.e 1 second)
        .retryWhen((err) => err.delay(1000))
        .subscribe((employeeData) => {
            if (employeeData == null) {
                this.statusMessage =
                    'Employee with the specified Employee Code does not exist';
            }
            else {
                this.employee = employeeData;
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            this.statusMessage =
                'Problem with the service. Please try again after sometime';
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: can you please edit my code with your logics @mittalbhatt

Answer (score 0):

```
Use observable.timer for your purpose in angular way.

  private timer;

constructor(private CartdataService: CartdataService, private http: HttpClient) {
}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.timer = Observable.timer(9000);
    this.timer.subscribe((t) => this.onTimeOut());
  }
   onTimeOut() {
    this.CartdataService.update_User_Session().then(
    success => {
    if(success ['ok'] == 0){
      console.log('test');
    }
    },
    error => { console.log(error); });
}

   ngOnDestroy(){
    console.log("Destroy timer");

  }
}
```